# When to set production mode in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

why should I set **production mode** and when it's the **correct time** to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MagentoDevDocs:

*You should run the Magento software in production mode when it’s deployed to a production server. After optimizing the server environment (database, web server, and so on), you should run the static view files deployment tool to write static view files to the Magento pub/static directory.
This improves performance because static files don’t go through the fallback mechanism; instead, URLs for static files are created as needed.*

In production mode:

Static view files are not materialized, and URLs for them are composed on the fly without going through the fallback mechanism. (Static view files are served from cache only.)
Errors are logged to the file system and are never displayed to the user.

For more information, [Click here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html)

Comment: If Its helpful for you, please mark it as an answer!